# use TypeConverter for toString Method for System.Drawing.Color Properties with localized names

Tags: c#, properties, localization, type-conversion

I would like to use a TypeConverter for a .net struct Property.

```
public class MyColorOptions
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(MyTypeConverter))]
    public Color MyColor{ get; set; }
}

public class MyTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

The ConvertTo Method is never called. This is only working with self created complex data types or classes.

I want to achieve that a Localized color name is returned by the toString() Method for the color Property.
A German color Translator can be found here: http://pastebin.com/sKtpjHND

I want to use the converter in combination with the ColorTranslator.

Would be nice from you if you could help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can add an Extension method to all enums which will use the type converter, and it's quite simple:

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string ToDisplayString(this Enum value)
    {
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(value);
        return converter.ConvertToString(value);
    }
}
```

then:

```
MyColorOptions.MyColor.ToDisplayString();
```